# Is shape drawable a shared object among views

Tags: android

I used a shape drawable from xml as a src for 2 image views in the layout XML

On the second imageview, I update the color of the drawable from green to red  through code
I noticed that the first image view had its drawable changed to red

I thought each imageview will have it's own version of drawable. Is this a shared object? Do I have to create 2 different drawable xmls in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not obvious, but that's true, the state of the drawable is shared across different instances and different ImageView's. I personally encountered the same unhandy behavior not so long ago.

The proof can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables

> Note: Each unique resource in your project can maintain only one state, no matter how many different objects you instantiate for it. For example, if you instantiate two Drawable objects from the same image resource and change a property (such as the alpha) for one object, then it also affects the other. When dealing with multiple instances of an image resource, instead of directly transforming the Drawable object you should perform a tween animation.

But luckily there is a solution build-in in Android SDK.
If you're already changing the state of the drawable in code, the solution would come in handy. To change the state of one and only one Drawable, you could use [Drawable.mutate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) method.

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html?m=1

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you